# Next.js | Next build fails when using ChakraUI - undefined reference to useMemo

Tags: reactjs, next.js, create-react-app, chakra-ui

I'm currently trying to migrate a create-react-app SPA to Next.js in the interest of SEO/bundle size/page performance and have been running into an issue with getting Next.js to play nicely with ChakraUI. When I run next build, I get the same error for all of my pages:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/graffiti". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')     at exports.useMemo (/home/anthonydibi/git/dibiagg.io/client/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:25:208)     at ThemeProvider (file:///home/anthonydibi/git/dibiagg.io/client/node_modules/@chakra-ui/system/dist/chunk-3ZTTLJBV.mjs:14:25)     at Wc (/home/anthonydibi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)     at Zc (/home/anthonydibi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)     at Z (/home/anthonydibi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)     at Zc (/home/anthonydibi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)     at Z (/home/anthonydibi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)     at Zc (/home/anthonydibi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)     at Z (/home/anthonydibi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)     at Zc (/home/anthonydibi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')     at exports.useMemo (/home/anthonydibi/git/dibiagg.io/client/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:25:208)     at ThemeProvider (file:///home/anthonydibi/git/dibiagg.io/client/node_modules/@chakra-ui/system/dist/chunk-3ZTTLJBV.mjs:14:25)     at Wc (/home/anthonydibi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)     at Zc (/home/anthonydibi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)     at Z (/home/anthonydibi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)     at Zc (/home/anthonydibi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)     at Z (/home/anthonydibi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)     at Zc (/home/anthonydibi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)     at Z (/home/anthonydibi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)     at Zc (/home/anthonydibi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')     at exports.useMemo (/home/anthonydibi/git/dibiagg.io/client/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:25:208)     at ThemeProvider (file:///home/anthonydibi/git/dibiagg.io/client/node_modules/@chakra-ui/system/dist/chunk-3ZTTLJBV.mjs:14:25)     at Wc (/home/anthonydibi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)     at Zc (/home/anthonydibi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)     at Z (/home/anthonydibi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)     at Zc (/home/anthonydibi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)     at Z (/home/anthonydibi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)     at Zc (/home/anthonydibi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)     at Z (/home/anthonydibi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)     at Zc (/home/anthonydibi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
```

The error seems to be coming from the ChakraUI ThemeProvider, which is run from the ChakraProvider at the root of the application I believe. For some reason the ThemeProvider is trying to use useMemo from React but does not have access?

Here is what my _app.js looks like:

```
import Layout from '../components/layout.js';
import '../styles/fonts.css';
import '../styles/swatches.css';
import '../styles/pdf.css';
import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import theme from '../styles/theme.js';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
            <Layout>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Layout>
        </ChakraProvider>
    );
}
```

and here is what my _document.js looks like:

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import { ColorModeScript } from '@chakra-ui/react'

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html lang="en" style="scroll-behavior:smooth">
      <Head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <meta
        name="dibiagg.io"
        content="Anthony Di Biaggio's personal website"
        />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.5.0/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-7EyYLQZgWBi67fBtVxw60/OWl1kjsfrPFcaU0pp0nAh+i8FD068QogUvg85Ewy1k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title>dibiagg.io</title>
      </Head>
      <body>
        <ColorModeScript />
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```

and my layout.js:

```
import Nav from './Nav.js'
import ContactFooter from './ContactFooter.js'
import Banner from './Banner.js'
import { FaGithub } from 'react-icons/fa'

export default function Layout({ children }) {
    return (
      <>
        <Banner header={"DIBIAGG.IO is open source!"} action={"Check it out on Github."} buttonText={"Go"} buttonIcon={<FaGithub />} onClick={() => {window.open("https://github.com/anthonydibi/dibiagg.io")}}/>
        <Nav /> 
        <main>{children}</main>
        <ContactFooter/>
      </>
    )
}
```

I have tried removing all theming from ChakraUI, but then it will just error out for an undefined useContext on another part of ChakraUI. I've tried removing the ChakraProvider as well but then I get similar errors for undefined react hooks in my components that use ChakraUI styles.

Comment: Are you using the "app" directory in Next.js? If so Chakra UI has some additional steps to follow https://chakra-ui.com/getting-started/nextjs-guide#app-directory-setup

Comment: No, I am not using the app directory. I don't really know what fixed my issue since it just suddenly started working, but I moved the Head element from _document to _app and some time after that it started working.